# ProgressDialog not shown in UIThread

Tags: android, progressdialog, ui-thread

I'm creating a map using the google api lib. Because the mapwidget takes a long time to load I'm trying to add a loading notification, but it isn't shown. I can show the progressDialog in regular threads though. How come this dialog isn't shown?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "Map = loading",false,true);
        //setContentView(R.layout.map);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Log.d("debug", "before setContentView");                        //13:36:25
                    setContentView(R.layout.map);
                    Log.d("debug", "after setContentView");                         //13:36:39

                } catch (Exception e) { }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }});

        initMap();     
        initGps();

    }
```

Comment: That's because both the mapwidget and the loading notification uses the same thread.

Comment: Can I push a new thread then? Or how can I solve this?

Comment: `onCreate()` runs on UI thread, so using `runOnUiThread()` just executes that immediately. 14 seconds are a lot, doesn't it go ANR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this as a solution:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/

Answer (score 1):

It is pointless to put up a `ProgressDialog` for a `MapActivity` because "the mapwidget takes a long time to load", because you have no way to know when the `MapView` is done loading, so  you have no way to know when to dismiss the dialog. `setContentView()` itself should run fairly quickly; the actual loading of the map tiles happens asynchronously.

Note that the time it takes to display a `MapView` is mostly dependent upon the Internet connection back to the Google Maps servers. In most cases, it does not take particularly long, certainly not long enough to warrant a `ProgressDialog`.