# Android : showDialog when setContentView loading

Tags: android, showdialog

There is a method for display an Indeterminate Dialog when setContentView loading ? I want to do this when the application load the google maps's mapView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485832/progressdialog-not-shown-in-uithread) guy had a similar issue and he used this solution. [LINK](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/).

hope you are able to find out how he did it.